# Is there a better (more correct) way to calculate modulus of some power than Math.pow?

Tags: java, math, floating-point

Consider the following simple block of Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int a = 7;
  double exp;
  for (int i=0; i<71; ++i) {
    exp = Math.pow(a,i) % 71;
    if (exp == 59.0)
      System.out.printf("k=%d: %.0f%n", i, exp);
  }
}
```

I am trying to iterate through all of the exponents k such that a^x=59 mod 71... however there should be only a single one, and I'm getting three: k=3, k=23, k=63. This is clearly wrong, as upon verification, only k=3 is the correct answer. Is there some inherent problem in the way floating point works (and thus `Math.pow`), or is there some other logic problem in my code? **Should I be using some other method to calculate a^x (mod n)?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest correct expedient that doesn't require writing your own method is probably

```
BigInteger.valueOf(a)
    .modPow(BigInteger.valueOf(i), BigInteger.valueOf(71))
    .intValue();
```

Comment: Interesting. Always nice to find new methods. I wasn't even aware that Java had a `BigInteger`, and for that matter, that it had methods like that..

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid "big calculations", then you can perform the modulo after every multiplication:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    for (int i=0,a=1; i<71; i++, a = (a*7)%71)
    {
        if (a == 59)
            System.out.println("k = " + i);
    }
}
```